# HTML close tag print in my page

Tags: php, html

Data or value in `$description` from database is

```
<div><a href="www.google.com">Henry</a></div>
```

My HTML Code

```
<input type="textbox" id="textbox" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="<?php echo $description; ?>"/>
```

Output : 
 [image: My Output]

If the code be

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value='<?php echo $description; ?>'/>
```

Its working fine !..Any one please tell me the issue ?

Comment: Your quotes are conflicting. Shouldn't you escape the HTML code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to have HTML code inside the value of a hidden input in a form? That doesn't sound right.

If you need to keep it as it is, you should at least use [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to make it a string:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlentities($description); ?>"/>
```

An example:

```
<?php
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);

// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

look at the different between " and ':

if your code is :

```
 $description = <div><a href="www.google.com">Henry</a></div>
```

and

```
 <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="<?php echo $description; ?>"/>
```

so it's actually means

```
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="<div><a href="www.google.com">Henry</a></div>"/>
```

and the " that before the url closes the "value", so the value is actually -

```
  value="<div><a href="
```

so try to use ' instead of " on the url (google) OR in the value (not both).

Answer (score 1):

Your code becomes like this...

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value = "<div><a href="www.google.com" > Henry </a></div> "/>
```

You can divide this as...

`<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value = "<div><a href="www.google.com" >`

`Henry`

`</a></div>`

`"/>`

That's how you get `Henry"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Here comes 2 issues,

1. First of all use [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to convert all applicable characters to HTML entities.

   ```
   htmlentities($description);
   ```
2. And Its fair to use Single quote instead of double quotes. Ref [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2)

   > By default, SGML requires that all attribute values be delimited using either double quotation marks (ASCII decimal 34) or single quotation marks (ASCII decimal 39). Single quote marks can be included within the attribute value when the value is delimited by double quote marks, and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

This is how your browser sees the code:

```
<input type="textbox" id="textbox" value="<div><a href="www.google.com">Henry</a></div>
"/>
```

See how the double-quotes don't make sense?

If you want to keep double-quotes you need to go with [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

```
$description = htmlentities($description);

<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="<?php echo $description; ?>"/>
```

Also, your link "www.google.com" will point to a page called www.google.com RELATIVE to your directory. Be sure to use ABSOLUTE path: http://www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

A simple replace in here like this

```
<div><a href='www.google.com'>Henry</a></div>
```

or like this

```
<input type="textbox" id="textbox" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value='<?php echo $description; ?>'/>
```

but **not** both should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Try this:

```
div><a href='www.google.com'>Henry</a></div>

<input type="textbox" id="textbox" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value='<?php echo strip_tags($description); ?>'/>
```